# Error while running project from eclipse

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have downloaded cocos2d x v3.3 beta and created a project in windows using this command

```
cocos.py new Tutorialv3cocos -p com.ghostdreamstudo.learning -l cpp -d D:\Development\Learning
```

Then i have imported project to eclipse and tried to run but eclipse gives me following error

```
[2014-10-03 18:40:39 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxAccelerometer;
[2014-10-03 18:40:39 - Tutorialv3cocos] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxAccelerometer;
```

Does anyone face the same problem or know how to solve this issue??

Comment: Check out included jars in Java Build Path.. you might have added duplicate jar files.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem before and was guided to remove Android dependencies from Java Build Path and it worked every time start up eclipse and do the removing for that session. As VPatidar mentioned, new Cocos2dx has some duplicate class org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxAccelerometer in two places. Remove one then that error disappears.

For any one still has this error, do one of these:

1. Remove libcocos2dx sources folder in Java Build Path > Source tab

or

2. Remove `android.library.reference.1=../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java` from `project.properties` file

I chose second.